# servlets in Java

Tags: java, class, jsp, servlets, action

What I want is to display a list of products with an "add to cart" button for each product. How will I associate that button with reference to the product?

i.e If I click to add an Item A to the cart, how will I specify in the button, to call the ShoppingCart class, from where the item will be added.

I already have a servlet, for populating all the products into an ArrayList, and the forward it to a JSP page.

```
<form action="products" method="get">
<table border=1>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.id}</td>
            <td>${product.description}</td>
            <td>${product.unitPrice}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add to cart" onlick="????"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the form in the `<td>` instead of around the table. Use `<inupt type="submit">` to let the button *really* function without the need for JavaScript hacks which would fail anyway on webbrowsers with JS disabled. Include a `<input type="hidden">` in the form to pass the product ID.

Summarized:

```
<table border=1>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.id}</td>
            <td>${product.description}</td>
            <td>${product.unitPrice}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="products" method="get">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${product.id}" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This way it'll be available as follows in `doGet()` method of the servlet listening on `/products`.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you'd like to use POST for this instead of GET. Otherwise the user will be able to add *another* product to his basket when s/he bookmarks the result page and opens it later, or when s/he just clicks/follows a link passed by another (potential malicious) person in an email/IM/site/etc. Replace `method="get"` by `method="post"` and move logic in `doGet()` to `doPost()`.

Comment: Ideally you'd use a POST instead of a GET for this, but this is the hot tip.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <td><a href="/yourShopKeeperServlet?productId=${product.id}"> <~-- Your Image Goes here --> </a></td>
```

It will make GET to servlet. and from there you can read

```
request.getParameter("productId");
```

Answer (score 1):

been ages tat i have worked on jsp's but i can give you the concept and leave the implementation to you.

- in each **tr** you will have a form, with hidden value of item_id and button in the form as submit action, and another hiden item named as "add"
- each form will submit to your one servlet, lets name it shoppingcart
- in servlet, while processing request, you will see if there is a parameter named "add". if yes, then you will get the parameter named "item_id" and will add that item to cart.

Answer (score 1):

You would call a function using the product id:

```
<td><input type="button" value="Add to cart" onlick="addToCart("+${product.id}+");"/></td>
```

and then an ajax call

```
function addToCart (id) {
    $.post("/cart", {prodId: id}, callback};
}
```

the servlet would be something like

```
public class CartServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String prodId= req.getParameter("prodId");
        // continue with the purchasing code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My doubt around these answers is that in each form within TR or TD there will be full page post request will occur that will be performance issue for the end user. He has to wait for page load every time he clicked the Add to cart button. What you can do is call an ajax function and post the URL with the ITEM_ID so that it will not cause you full page post. To enable the cart entry have a inline JSP that will be refreshed with the Form Post in order to get the details of the Cart entries.

Alternatively You can call a JSP function to add the Items in the Array that Will be passed a Session object while submitting the request.  There is lot of posts are present to Give you better understanding of this implementation.

[onClick function call using scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385927/onclick-function-call-using-scriptlet)