# Java method calls on page refresh in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have to call a Java method based on a button click event, but method is being called when i refresh the page. Is there a way to restrict the call only when the button is clicked? please help me

This is my jsp code:

```
 <%@ page language="java" import="sourcejava.*"%>
 <%
 if(request.getParameter("btnsubmit") != null)
 {
    Xmlparse p = new Xmlparse();
    p.parse();
 }
 %> 

<input type="button" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="parse"/>
```

Comment: Your button, unless you haven't shown some javascript, doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sending a GET request? If so then that will be in your URL. So when you refresh that parameter will be sent along in your URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385927/onclick-function-call-using-scriptlet, button is of type submit, Hope it helps.